How to feed lightmap in GPU instanced meshes in Unity?
Unity's documentation state that GPU Instancing supports baked lighting:

Since Unity 2018.1, Global Illumination (GI) rendering is supported by GPU Instancing in the form of light probes, occlusion probes (in Shadowmask mode) and lightmap STs. Standard shaders and surface shaders have GI support automatically enabled.

However, I could not find a way to feed lightmap in GPU-instanced objects. Do you guys have any ideas?
